# Dynamically add elements from top and remove same number of elements from bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here I have made function for adding n number of div and at a same time n number of divs are  removed.But in my code i append div from bottom and remove div from top.I just want to reverse from it.Divs should be added at top and removed from bottom.

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/xddn8x04/3/

```
<div class="visible-md visible-lg sidebar">
        <div class="follow-box" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="200">
            <!-- <div>You may follow</div> -->

            <div class="follow-container">
                <div class="follow_title">People you may follow</div>
                    <div class="set-follow">
                        <div class="follow">
                            <div class="sidebar-img">
                                 <div class="img-block">
                                     <img class="pic" alt="Mikhael Ross" src="assets/img/person.png" height="60" width="60">
                                 </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="center-block">
                                 <div class="name">Malica Ross</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="follow">
                            <div class="sidebar-img">
                                <div class="img-block">
                                    <img class="pic" alt="Mikhael Ross" src="assets/img/person.png" height="60" width="60">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="center-block">
                                <div class="name">Ajmal Bilal</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="follow">
                            <div class="sidebar-img">
                                <div class="img-block">
                                    <img class="pic" alt="Mikhael Ross" src="assets/img/person.png" height="60" width="60">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="center-block">
                                <div class="name">Shung ching</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="follow">
                            <div class="sidebar-img">
                                <div class="img-block">
                                    <img class="pic" alt="Mikhael Ross" src="assets/img/person.png" height="60" width="60">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="center-block">
                                <div class="name">Shrew mykong</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="follow">
                            <div class="sidebar-img">
                                <div class="img-block">
                                    <img class="pic" alt="Mikhael Ross" src="assets/img/person.png" height="60" width="60">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="center-block">
                                <div class="name">Fenny Sharma</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="hide-follow"></div>
                </div>

            <div class="follow-suggestions"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

---

```
 var followContainer = function() {
        var countdown;
        var count = 0;
        var _addContent = function(count) {
            var followlen = +$('.follow-container .set-follow > .follow').length;
            var _followcontent = ('.follow-suggestions .follow-container');
            var follow = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                follow = ('<div class="follow"><div class="sidebar-img"><div class="img-block"><img class="pic" alt="Mikhael Ross" src="assets/img/person.png" height="60" width="60"><div class="side-icon"><i class="fa fa-plus sidebar-icon"></i></div></div></div><div class="center-block"><div class="name">mayank bliss</div><div class="detail">45777 followers</div></div><div class="right-block"><div title="May 22, 2015" class="date">2015-05-22</div></div></div>');
                $(follow).hide().appendTo('.follow-container .hide-follow').fadeIn(
                        '1000');
                $('.follow-container .set-follow').append(
                        $(".follow-container .hide-follow >.follow"));
                $(".follow-container .set-follow >.follow:visible:lt(" + count + ")").fadeOut(
                '1000');
            }

        }
        var _events = function() {
            var timeoutHandle = window.setTimeout(function() {
                _addContent(1)
            }, 5000);
            setTimeout(function() {
                _addContent(2)
            }, 8000);
        }
        var _init = function() {
            _events();
        }
        return {
            init : _init
        }
  }();
  $(document).ready(function() {
        followContainer.init();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

`$('.someParentClass')('.someClass').slice(-5).remove();`

to remove last 5 divs of class `someClass` inside some `someParentClass', and if`$abc` is the html you want to add on the top use

`$(".someParentClass").prepend($abc)` or
`$(".someParentClass").html($abc+$(".someParentClass").html())`

Comment: Thanks for the help and response I will check it on my project @void

Comment: I fixed value of elements in container.suppose I need to show only 5 at a time. If 2 elements are coming at a same time 2 elements should be removed.In this scenario is it going to work?@void